# How to set the type for each column from a row?

Tags: r, data.table

When I work with my own data, I like to creat a dataset in this way :

| birthdate | height | sick | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| date | numeric | logical | list |
| Date of birth | Weight (cm) | Is the patient sick ? | Hair color |
| 20/03/1991 | 163 | 1 | blue |
| 10/11/1993 | 185 | 0 | brown |

## Creating a new dataset

I like to keep the original dataset, and create a new one without the 2 first rows.

```
data_work <- data.table::copy(data.table::as.data.table(data))
data_work <- ds_work[i = -c(1:2)]
```

| birthdate | height | sick | color |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 20/03/1991 | 163 | 1 | blue |
| 10/11/1993 | 185 | 0 | brown |

## Labels

Then, I can use the 2nd row of the original dataset to label every columns.

```
label_colname <- as.character(data[2,])
data_work <- sjlabelled::set_label(data_work, label = label_colname)
```

## Col types

I would like to basically do the same and use the first row of the original dataset to control all of my columns types. Is it possible ?

*Note : I work with `data.table` and possible col types include : "skip", "guess", "logical", "numeric", "date", "text" or "list"*

Comment: If you want this, all columns will be converted to character.. Is that correct?

Comment: @Wimpel No because when I import the data, I delete the second row (but I can keep it in another dataset/vector)

Comment: Then I cannot come up with a usecase for which this would be a good idea... why not just use `sapply(mydata, class)` to get the classes then?

Comment: This inefficient, also an unneeded copy of your table. Not sure how you read the data, but one would consider a readLines for your 2st two rows and then read the data with skip first 2 rows. Probably your data will be in the correct type already (not like now all will be character).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a general method for whatever "types" you may need.

The first premise is that we have unambiguous functions for each of the types you may have, namely

```r
funcs <- list(
  guess   = function(z) type.convert(z, as.is = TRUE),
  skip    = identity,
  logical = function(z) !is.na(z) & tolower(z) %in% c("1", "true"),
  numeric = as.numeric,
  date    = function(z) as.Date(z, format = "%d/%m/%Y"),
  text    = as.character,
  list    = as.list)
```

Basic cleanup of the data to extract the types,

```r
types <- unlist(data_work[1,])
labels <- unlist(data_work[2,])
data_work <- data_work[-(1:2),]
data_work
#     birthdate height   sick  color
#        <char> <char> <char> <char>
# 1: 20/03/1991    163      1   blue
# 2: 10/11/1993    185      0  brown
```

From here, we'll `Map` each column over its respective function:

```r
cols <- names(data_work)[ types %in% names(funcs) ]
funs <- funcs[ types[ types %in% names(funcs) ] ]
data_work[, (cols) := Map(function(f, x) f(x), funs, .SD), 
           .SDcols = cols]
#     birthdate height   sick  color
#        <Date>  <num> <lgcl> <list>
# 1: 1991-03-20    163   TRUE   blue
# 2: 1993-11-10    185  FALSE  brown
```

---

Data

```r
data_work <- structure(list(birthdate = c("date", "Date of birth", "20/03/1991", "10/11/1993"), height = c("numeric", "Weight (cm)", "163", "185"), sick = c("logical", "Is the patient sick ?", "1", "0"), color = c("list", "Hair color", "blue", "brown")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -4L))
setDT(data_work)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
data <- read.csv("data.csv", sep=",", header= TRUE)
data <- as.data.table(data)
```

when `data` is the data-table from your question including the first row (with the data types) after the header with column names, then the following will give you all columns with e.g. `"date"` in the first row as `date_columns` and then change the data type of these columns accordingly.

```
date_columns <- colnames(data)[grepl("date",data[1,])]
data[ ,(date_columns) := lapply(.SD, as.Date), .SDcols = date_columns]
```

just repeat these two steps for every type you want to detect (replace "date" in the code for the other data types). Afterward you can delete the first row where you specified the types from your data-table.